# Making HTTP form POST request

Tags: json, curl

I'm trying to make a HTTP form POST request to http://example.co.uk.
I used `curl http://example.co.uk -d @example.json`. However it gives me error saying it should only contain single field called application.

example.json file:

```
{"application":[
    {
      "name":"John",
      "email":"john@example.com",
      "github":"https://github.com/john",
      "twitter":"https://twitter.com/john",
    }
  ]
}
```

What's the correct way to do it? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is returning that error? The server or `curl`? I may be the format of the payload is not the one the server is expecting.

Comment: When I type "curl http://example.co.uk -d @example.json" in the command line it gives back "Your application should contain a single field called application". Not sure what is giving the error.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't believe http://example.co.uk is the real service you are trying to use.

Comment: No it's just an example url. I'm trying to submit my example.json file to that url. I'm new to this so not sure if i'm doing it right

Comment: Yes, the command is correct. You can check it with http://requestb.in/. The problem is the service.

Comment: requestb.in worked fine though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to indicate to the server that the content type is JSON instead of the standard form-encoded data, so use:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://example.co.uk -d @example.json
```

Also, your JSON file should be valid JSON i.e. without any ending/redundant `,` characters, so:

```
{"application":[
    {
      "name":"John",
      "email":"john@example.com",
      "github":"https://github.com/john",
      "twitter":"https://twitter.com/john"
    }
  ]
}
```

Check the contents at http://jsonlint.com

Comment: Looks better but got this error now "We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)".

Comment: Awesome bro that worked but do you know how to make JSON-encoded dictionary. Now I get the error saying "Your 'application' parameter isn't a dictionary."

Comment: remove `[` and `]` but you should really consult the app docs to learn how to construct valid requests; that would be just guessing on my part